# How to show datepicker under text

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm having some trouble to show datepicker if I click on a `<span></span>` tag.

Here is my fiddle :

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#new_date" ).datepicker({
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: -7,
        maxDate: "10D",
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
            //$('form#set_new_date').submit();
        }
    });
} );
$('#date_picker').click(function(){
    $('#new_date').datepicker('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<span id="date_picker" style="font-size: 40px; cursor: pointer;">
    <span>Monday 04 January</span>
</span>
<form id="set_new_date" method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="new_date" id="new_date">
</form>
```

My point is: how can I pick date only when I click on the `span` tag ? I would like to remove or hide the input `new_date`

Comment: you mean you just want to hide the box? Then you can add "visibilty: hidden" in CSS to your input. and only the selector will appear when you click the span

Comment: @Warden330 Yes but the datepicker "box" need to appear centered and under the tag span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: this is how i would position the Selector-field, might need to make some changes depending on how your complete page is build. The Code is commented where i made changes
Edit2: i added a line in the Jquery, commented again. With this solution you dont need the margin: auto anymore.

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#new_date" ).datepicker({
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: -7,
        maxDate: "10D",
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
            //$('form#set_new_date').submit();
        }
    });
} );
$('#date_picker').click(function(){
  //append the datepicker to a specific element in your html(bottom of the elector-div, below the span)
  $('.date_selector').append($('#ui-datepicker-div'));
    $('#new_date').datepicker('show');
    //as the styling of the field is basically inline css you can just override it with JQuery, remove left and right, remove position absolute.
    $("#ui-datepicker-div").css({ 'left' : '', 'right' : '', 'position' : '' });
});
```

```css
/*alignment of the box and the span*/
.date_selector {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
/*new class for the effect*/
.hiddenbox {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!--New Div to position the Span and the Box-->
<div class="date_selector">
  <span id="date_picker" style="font-size: 40px; cursor: pointer;">
      <span>Monday 04 January</span>
  </span>
  <form id="set_new_date" method="post" action="#">
      <input type="text" name="new_date" id="new_date" class="hiddenbox">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The input need to be hidden

Comment: ooohhh you want the Selector-Field to be centered and the Input gone, now i understood, sorry

Comment: @executable i edited my answer, you can check if thats what you meant

Comment: Thanks for the edit, the datepicker is not well placed. It's on the bottom of my page and not under the span

Comment: @executable alright, edited again. Like this the Selector should be part of the date-selector Div and not on the bottom of the page anymore

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky, but try this -

```js
$(function() {
  $("#new_date").datepicker({
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: -7,
    maxDate: "10D",
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      //$('form#set_new_date').submit();
    }
  });
});
$('#date_picker').click(function() {
  $('#new_date').show();
  $('#new_date').datepicker('show');
  $('#new_date').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<span id="date_picker" style="font-size: 40px; cursor: pointer;">
  <span>Monday 04 January</span>
</span>
<form id="set_new_date" method="post" action="#">
  <input type="text" name="new_date" id="new_date" style="display: none">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `opacity:0` on `text-box`

```
#new_date{opacity:0}
```

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#new_date" ).datepicker({
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: -7,
        maxDate: "10D",
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
            //$('form#set_new_date').submit();
        }
    });
} );
$('#date_picker').click(function(){
    $('#new_date').datepicker('show');
});
```

```css
#new_date{opacity:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<span id="date_picker" style="font-size: 40px; cursor: pointer;">
    <span>Monday 04 January</span>
</span>
<form id="set_new_date" method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="new_date" id="new_date">
</form>
```

Comment: Works great but how can I center it under the span tag ?